# parsing numbers in a string

Tags: ruby, algorithm, parsing

I'm trying to get my code to pass this test. If you've ever played magic the gathering, this might look familiar to you.

```
    Test.assert_equals(can_cast("11RB","10B","1R"), true)
    Test.assert_equals(can_cast("13BBRR","10BR","2R","B"), true)
```

But I can't seem to parse the correct numbers out of the elements correctly. Does anyone see a flaw in my code that's keeping me from passing these test?

```
def can_cast(hand, *spell_cost)
  colored_mana_hand = Array.new
  colored_mana_cost_aggregate = Array.new
  colored_mana_spent = Array.new

  colorless_mana_hand_array = []
  colorless_mana_hand = 0

  colorless_mana_cost_array = []
  colorless_mana_cost_aggregate_array = []
  colorless_mana_cost_aggregate = 0


  hand.split("").each do |i|
    if i.to_i != 0                        # extracting existing colorless mana from hand
    colorless_mana_hand_array << i
    else
    colored_mana_hand << i
    end
  end
  colorless_mana_hand = colorless_mana_hand_array.join.to_i

  spell_cost.each do |i|                   # extracting existing colorless mana from cost
    i.split("").each do |j|
      if j.to_i != 0                  
      colorless_mana_cost_array << j
    else
      colored_mana_cost_aggregate << j
    end
    end
      colorless_mana_cost_aggregate_array << colorless_mana_cost_array.join
      colorless_mana_cost_array.clear
  end

    colorless_mana_cost_aggregate_array.each do |i|
    colorless_mana_cost_aggregate += i.to_i
  end

    colored_mana_cost_aggregate.each do |i|                                                  # pay colored mana first
     if colored_mana_hand.include?(i)
       colored_mana_spent << i
       colored_mana_hand.rotate(colored_mana_hand.index(i)).shift
     end
  end

  (colored_mana_spent.sort == colored_mana_cost_aggregate.sort) && (colored_mana_hand.length + colorless_mana_hand) >= colorless_mana_cost_aggregate 
end
```

Comment: I have never played _Magic: The Gathering_. Should `"10BR"` really be interpreted as `1`, `0` / `"B"`, `"R"` (two digits and two letters) or is it `10` / `"B"`, `"R"` (one number and two letters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a funny way to pull numbers out of the string. It would probably be easier to use `scan`, here is how you can use it:

```
# extracting existing colorless
colorless_mana_hand_array = hand.scan(/\d/).join.to_i
```

This will extract the digits from the string into an array, join them, and then convert to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone see a flaw in my code that's keeping me from passing these test?

Yes, Indeed.

You split your `spell_cost` strings via:

```
i.split("").each do |j|
  # ...
end
```

The code will yield each single character to the block. For `"10BR"` this gives:

```
"10BR".split("").each do |j|
  p j: j
end
```

Output:

```
{:j=>"1"}
{:j=>"0"}
{:j=>"B"}
{:j=>"R"}
```

Furthermore you have this check:

```
if j.to_i != 0
  colorless_mana_cost_array << j
else
  colored_mana_cost_aggregate << j
end
```

For the above input, you get

```
colorless_mana_cost_array   #=> ["1"]
colored_mana_cost_aggregate #=> ["0", "B", "R"]
```

Because `"0".to_i != 0` evaluate to `false`, just like `"B"` and `"R"`.

If I understand your code correctly, `"0"` should go into the `colorless_mana_cost_array`.